# How to write multi-languages projects in python?

Tags: python, gettext

I want to build a multi-languages python program. based on these links([1](https://simpleit.rocks/python/how-to-translate-a-python-project-with-gettext-the-easy-way/),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9828629/4417806)), I structured and build my program in the following format.

```
+---commandHandlers
|   |   agreements.py
|   |   basics.py
|   |   __init__.py
|
+---responseTexts
|   |   agreementResponces.py
|   |   basicResponces.py
|   |   __init__.py
|   |
|   +---locales
|   |   |   default.pot
|   |   |   ReadMe.md
|   |   |
|   |   \---fa
|   |       \---LC_MESSAGES
|   |               default.mo
|   |               default.po
```

I have two problems.

the first thing is every time that I add new text which is needed to be translated,  I should use following commands and it's ruined my previous translated data.

```
cd responseTexts
xgettext -d default -o locales/default.pot basicResponces.py agreementResponces.py
cp locales/default.pot locales/fa/LC_MESSAGES/default.po
msgfmt -o locales/fa/LC_MESSAGES/default.mo locales/fa/LC_MESSAGES/default
```

I know that instead of using `cp`, I could copy-paste newly generated texts, but as you know it's very boring and unreasonable.

and my second question is how can I change default.pot`s header from

```
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=CHARSET\n"
```

to

```
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
```

?

before I forget, is there any way to give directory as input to `xgettext` in windows? cuz the bellow command, doesn't work for me.

```
xgettext -d default -o locales/default.pot -D .
```

**Updated**

using msgmerge as `msgmerge locales/fa/LC_MESSAGES/default.po locales/default.pot > locales/fa/LC_MESSAGES/default.po` doesn't work too :))

Comment: for more information, I have fined `polib`, but I don't think that it is what I want, I'm looking for sth like `vue-gettext-tools` which is mentioned [here](https://github.com/gmarty/xgettext/issues/72)

Comment: Well after thinking a while about it, I am unable to write a correct SO answer for that question. The answer is in the doc for [GNU gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html) and notably the `msgmerge` command. But I could not extract a short enough text from it.

Comment: Dear @SergeBallesta thanks for your reply, I tried what you said, using `msgmerge locales/fa/LC_MESSAGES/default.po locales/default.pot` shows me what I want, but the interesting part is that when I want to write the result with `>` command to `locales/fa/LC_MESSAGES/default.po`, first the headers part got lost and again, my previous translated texts got erased :))